# Window Server 2012 throttling incoming IPv6 network file sharing operations

Tags: ipv6, windows-server-2012, throttling

## Short version

- IPv4 download from server: *fast*
- IPv4 upload to server: *fast*
- IPv6 download from server: *fast*
- IPv6 upload to server: ***slow***

[image]

## Full version

I am copying files from a GBe desktop to a GBe server. The copy proceeds at a *horrendously* slow:

- 23 kB/s
- i.e. 0.2 Mbps
- 1% of GBe

[image: Slow moving progress]

But if I copy a file to a *virtual machine* hosted *inside* that same GBe server, copy proceeds as normal (512 Mbps = 50% of GBe):

[image: Normal moving progress]

I thought to myself, *"What can Windows Server 2012 possibly being doing, that the **virtual** Windows Server 2003 is not?"*

## What about...

- It cannot be a cabling issue, as both transfers go across the same cables, through the same switch.
- It cannot be a drive speed issue, as the targets of both file copies end up on the same drive (a Storage Space parity drive).
- It cannot be drive write speed issue, as I can copy files locally around on the destination drive, at full speed (111 MB/s = 888 Mbps).
- It is not network speed, as I can **download** from the server at 994 Mbps.

As I was pinging both servers, I realized I was communicating:

- *old* server over **IPv4**
- *new* server over **IPv6**

Which then led me to my final, frustrating, test:

- Download from the server over IPv6
- and upload back to the same server over IPv4

And it's fast:

```
 Desktop                \\corsair (IPv6 identity)
+----------+           +--------------------------------+
|          | 994Mbps   |                                |
|          |<──────────|                                |  
|          |           |                                |
|          | 0.2Mbps   |                                |
|          |──────────>|                                |
|          |           |                                |
|        ┌─|<──────────|                                |
|        │ |           ┇                               ┇ 
|        │ |           |\\192.168.1.245 (IPv4 Identity) |
|        │ | 504Mbps   |                                |
|        └─|──────────>|                                |
|          |           |                                |
+----------+           +--------------------------------+
```

What is Windows Server 2012 doing that is causing it to fail so *horrendeously* on receiving IPv6 packets?

**Note**: I would have tried to test uploading over IPv6 to the virtual machine inside, but Windows XP/Server 2003 did not support **File Sharing** over IPv6 (cannot resolve the NetBIOS name).

## Machines

- **Desktop**: Windows 7 64-bit
     IPv6 MTU: 1472
     IPv4 MTU: 1472
- **Server**: Windows Server 2012
     IPv6 MTU: 1472
     IPv4 MTU: 1472

Bonus: the MTU setting on client and server 1472:

```
>netsh interface ipv6 show subinterfaces

   MTU  MediaSenseState   Bytes In  Bytes Out  Interface
------  ---------------  ---------  ---------  -------------
  1472                1  11739088006  581016212  Local Area Connection
```

## The Questions

- **Why** is uploading IPv6 slow?
- **Why** is downloading IPv6 not slow?
- **Why** is IPv4 not slow?
- What setting must be adjusted to fix it?

## Update

It's a litter over a year later, and the problem remains unsolved. Today i switched my desktop back to backup to the network server. It's a few hours later and the backup is still going. I remembered that Windows Server 2012 is slow when trying to send it IPv6 packets:

[image]

Comment: The 1472 MTU isn't normal for a _native_ IPv6 connection. Are you tunneling IPv6 directly to this machine?

Comment: @MichaelHampton These two machines are on the same LAN. But there is a router, that routes IPv6 packets to the Internet.**That** router is connected to the IPv6 Internet using a tunnel.

Comment: What's the MTU on the other machine? And of your tunnel?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Both client and server (IPv6) MTU is 1472. (Question updated)

Comment: Looks like we've found the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What is the problem? (an MTU other than 1500 is not a problem)